# Set a default for field terminators when exporting/importing

Tags: mysql

When exporting data from MySQL, I almost always specify `FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'` because the results get opened in Excel (which handles comma-separated values better than tab-separated).

Is there any way (compile option/obscure setting) to set `","` as the field terminator when using `INTO OUTFILE` and `LOAD DATA INFILE` to avoid writing the above for every query?

Answer (score 0):

Being explicit in your commands is never a bad thing, especially for application (and developer!) portability—imagine someone new starts development on your project without being aware that it depends on a customised MySQL binary.

In the latest Generally Available (GA) release of MySQL Community Server, version 5.5.28 (as of writing), the defaults are hard-coded into [`sql/sql_class.cc`](http://fossies.org/dox/mysql-5.5.28/sql__class_8cc_source.html):

```
2074: static String default_line_term("\n",default_charset_info);
2075: static String default_escaped("\\",default_charset_info);
2076: static String default_field_term("\t",default_charset_info);
```

If you're considering compiling a custom binary, you could create your own fork.